# Image not persisting DataViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, adapter

I have a list of images that I am displaying. I am successfully fetching the images and setting the image to the ImageView.

But the problem is whenever I scroll the list of images the image view tends to load image of some other imageview . i.e randomly changing the images of the imageview.

I want once the image is loaded get gets persisted to their respective imageview.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    dish = dishes.get(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dish_summary, parent,
            false);
    image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dish_image);
    Log.i("image",String.valueOf(image.getTag()));
    if (image.getTag() == null){
    new LoadImage().execute(dish.getImage());   
    }       
    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    return rowView;
}


private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Menu ....");
            pDialog.show();
    }
       protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
         try {
              bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
      return bitmap;
       }
       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap img) {

         if(img != null)
         {
          image.setImageBitmap(img);
          image.setTag(img);
          pDialog.dismiss();
         }else
         {
           pDialog.dismiss();
           Toast.makeText(context, "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the GetView() method is called to recycle / repaint the List whenever it goes out of sight. The image tries to redraw itself.

To solve my problem I used and external library [SmartImageView](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/) which allows images to be loaded from URLs and Images are cached to memory and to disk for super fast loading.

Hope this helps !!